# Exception being thrown multiple times

Tags: c#

Basically I am ting  to catch any exception off a block of code, and fire said code one.

```
try {
     CODE
catch (Exception e) 
{
     DO THIS ONCE
} 
finally 
{
     CODE
}
```

**In Depth**

So I have been creating a TCP/SOCKET Server. Which can work with multiple clients. And send/recite (I/O) Data. It works well, and has been for a long time now. But I have found in my console that it says this:

[image: MyConsole]

This is bad because if it thinks the user disconnected twice it can create many problems. The way I know if a user has disconnected is by sending data to them every 200ms. And if there is a error then print they disconnected remove them from the client list, and disconnect there stream/tcp.

```
 static bool currentlyUsing;
    private static void PingClient(Object o)
    {
        if (!currentlyUsing)
        {
            if (clientsConnected.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (Client c in clientsConnected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        c.tcp.Client.Blocking = false;

                        c.tcp.Client.Send(new byte[1], 0, 0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        currentlyUsing = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Client Dissconnected: IP:" + c.ip + " PORT:" + c.port.ToString() + " Reason:" + e.Message);
                        clientsConnected.Remove(c);
                        c.tcp.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        currentlyUsing = false;
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to make it so it catches it only once, or catches it multiple times but only fires the code I want once?

Comment: There must also be some code where you receive from your client. When you receive 0 bytes, then this means he closed his socket and then you must do the same. Your ping mechanism is good for other kind of failures.

Comment: are you calling this code on a timer? whats the timeout on the send? mt guess if you are firing up another ping before you have completed the first loop through

Comment: Yes I am on a timer.

Comment: you need to make it more thread safe. maybe add a 'pinging in progress' flag to the client object

Comment: Humm, or maybe a disconnect cool-down.

Comment: Really all I need fixed, is that the exception is only fired once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making multiple timers. So it overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly: you want to *try* to run the code on each iteration of the `foreach` block, and always run the *finally* code for each iteration, but only run the `catch` code once?

If so:

Before the `foreach` block, define:

```
bool caught = false;
```

And then after:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (caught == false)
    {
        caught = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I have tried. I think the reason it is not working is because a timer is setting it off.

Comment: Timer t = new Timer(PingClient, null, 0, 200);

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Says in the image of the console in my question. Where it says reason: